# Правильное развертывание java-приложения на heroku

Tags: java, git, развертывание, heroku

Как правильно развернуть java-приложение на heroku? Я пытался развернуть java-бота для телеграмма при помощи heroku git.И судя по консоли все получилось:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но что делать дальше? Я попытался нажать на `open app` на heroku. Но получил следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что показали логи heroku:

> 2018-06-09T14:20:10.958368+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=botpasta.herokuapp.com request_id=da970fcd-4202-4f74-bf73-4d8394257fcd fwd="185.253.97.154" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>   2018-06-09T14:20:12.302663+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=botpasta.herokuapp.com request_id=2ef746ef-2a0f-4b37-a071-07b3895af7ab fwd="185.253.97.154" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

**upd**

Добавил `Procfile` в корневую папку проекта:

```
worker: sh/target/bin/SimpleTBot
```

И так же добавил скрипт из одного из примеров в pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>MainClass</mainClass>
                        <name>SimpleTBot</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Но при запуске приложения в heroku  я все еще получаю:

> Application error
>   An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: Скорее всего, нет Procfile. У хероку есть отличные гайды по деплою приложений на разных языках. В них и читайте.

Comment: @StasDorozhko Я добавил upd в свой вопрос, можете посмотреть?

Comment: [Отсюда](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#define-a-procfile): The Procfile in the example app you deployed looks like this: `web: java -jar target/java-getting-started-1.0.jar`. В этом файле должна содержаться команда, которая запустит Ваше приложение. Сейчас у Вас ругается в логах, что нет запущенного процесса. Если правильно напишете команду, то все запустится. В логах будет написано, что-то типа `state changed from down to up` (или как-то так)

Comment: логи я получаю при нажатии на `open app`: `2018-06-12T07:07:51.977305+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=botpasta.herokuapp.com request_id=05225f66-a086-4d78-a406-83d0721e9385 fwd="85.12.251.105" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-06-12T07:07:52.301228+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=botpasta.herokuapp.com request_id=6ceb4232-2d1c-426a-a4e7-ee49c124e695 fwd="85.12.251.105" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

Comment: @StasDorozhko А вот 2 лога с пометкой `state changed`: 1) `2018-06-12T06:42:47.410161+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up`    2)`2018-06-12T06:42:49.908581+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed`